# My first puzzle combination: A Nonogram and Hidato

Tags: logical-deduction, visual, grid-deduction, nonogram

Today's puzzle is a bit strange. Why, you might ask? Because it is a Nonogram and a Hidato combined!

Rules of Nonogram:

> The grid must be colored or left blank according to numbers at the side of the grid to reveal a hidden pixel art-like picture.

Rules of Hidato:

> To fill the grid with a series of consecutive numbers adjacent to each other orthogonally or diagonally. All tiles are required to be filled in.

The puzzle:

---

[image]

---

Hint 1:

> Solve the Nonogram first since the numbers in the Hidato can't go on the tiles that are filled in, although if it's too difficult to do that, you can partially solve the Hidato to help.

Hint 2:

> The lowest and highest numbers for the Hidato are already on the grid.

To get the green checkmark:

> 1. Finish both the Hidato and Nonogram
> 2. Explain the steps taken to solve the puzzle.

GLHF! (Good Luck Have Fun!) :D

Comment: I believe the Hidato solution is not unique.

Comment: I can verify that it is not unique. There are at least 3 boxes that can be one of two numbers and a solution can be formed.

Comment: @ibanezplyr wait, like as in you've already tried solving/solved the nonogram? I can't visualize what you're saying.

Comment: The Nonogram was good, it was the Hidato that had at least two solutions.

Comment: The visual tag is used for any puzzle that revolves around an image; just like the puzzle you have here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the Nonogram

> The two threes at the bottom tell you that every box but the center containing the 1 is a colored box. Following the logic from the top clues, this means the two left most and the two right most boxes are colored in. The ones are easy after that. The top row is the only place left to place boxes, and there are only three 1s left.

> step 1 [image]

> step 2 [image]

> step 3 [image]

Onto the Hidato!

> The one tells you where to start. Honestly, I just shifted numbers around until the fit. As mentioned in the OP comments, there are at least two solutions to this puzzle. I will post an image of the two I found.

> Solution 1 [image] Solution 2 [image]